# AWS RDS with Postgres : Is OOM killer configured

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are running load test against an application that hits a Postgres database.

During the test, we suddenly get an increase in error rate.
After analysing the platform and application behaviour, we notice that:

- CPU of Postgres RDS is 100%
- Freeable memory drops on this same server

And in the postgres logs, we see:

> 2018-08-21 08:19:48 UTC::@:[XXXXX]:LOG:  server process (PID XXXX) was terminated by signal 9: Killed

After investigating and reading documentation, it appears one possibility is linux oomkiller running having killed the process.

But since we're on RDS, we cannot access system logs /var/log messages to confirm.

So can somebody:

- confirm that oom killer really runs on AWS RDS for Postgres
- give us a way to check this ?
- give us a way to compute max memory used by Postgres based on number of connections ?

I didn't find the answer here:

- http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/server-process-was-terminated-by-signal-9-killed/
- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOR%3Dd%3D25iOzXpZFY%3DSjL%3DWD0noBL2Fio9LwpvO2%3DSTnjTW%3DMqQ%40mail.gmail.com
- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/04e301d1fee9%24537ab200%24fa701600%24%40JetBrains.com

Comment: Smells like the OOM killer alright. Reduce `max_connections` and/or `work_mem`.

Comment: thanks, but what is the formula ? If have 32 GB available on RDS instance. Regards

Comment: There is no formula. It is `shared_buffers` + all memory used by PostgreSQL backends. Each backend can use `work_mem` per sort, hash or bitmap operation, but there can be several such operations in a query.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, work_mem=4MB, shared_buffers=7994MB and I have 1000 Connections in AWS monitoring dashboard and max_connections=3518 , AFAIU, I would consume up to 12GB, my box has 32 GiB, so I don't understand how I can reach the oom limits.

Comment: I don't understand either, but your `max_connections` is insanely high. If you need that many connections, use a connection pool.

Comment: Maybe you should get decent hosting where you can have a look at the operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS maintains a page with best practices for their RDS service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html

In terms of memory allocation, that's the recommendation:

> An Amazon RDS performance best practice is to allocate enough RAM so
>   that your working set resides almost completely in memory. To tell if
>   your working set is almost all in memory, check the ReadIOPS metric
>   (using Amazon CloudWatch) while the DB instance is under load. The
>   value of ReadIOPS should be small and stable. If scaling up the DB
>   instance class—to a class with more RAM—results in a dramatic drop in
>   ReadIOPS, your working set was not almost completely in memory.
>   Continue to scale up until ReadIOPS no longer drops dramatically after
>   a scaling operation, or ReadIOPS is reduced to a very small amount.
>   For information on monitoring a DB instance's metrics, see [Viewing DB Instance Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html#USER_Monitoring).

Also, that's their recommendation to troubleshoot possible OS issues:

> Amazon RDS provides metrics in real time for the operating system (OS)
>   that your DB instance runs on. You can view the metrics for your DB
>   instance using the console, or consume the Enhanced Monitoring JSON
>   output from Amazon CloudWatch Logs in a monitoring system of your
>   choice. For more information about Enhanced Monitoring, see [Enhanced
>   Monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html)

There's a lot of good recommendations there, including query tuning.

Note that, as a last resort, you could switch to [Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/), which is compatible with PostgreSQL:

> Aurora features a distributed, fault-tolerant, self-healing storage
>   system that auto-scales up to 64TB per database instance. Aurora
>   delivers high performance and availability with up to 15 low-latency
>   read replicas, point-in-time recovery, continuous backup to Amazon S3,
>   and replication across three Availability Zones.

**EDIT**: talking specifically about your issue w/ PostgreSQL, check this [Stack Exchange thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206448/postgresql-large-transaction-oom-killer) -- they had a long connection with auto commit set to false.

> We had a long connection with auto commit set to false:
>
> `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`
>
> During that time we were doing a lot
>   of small queries and a few queries with a cursor:
>
> `statement.setFetchSize(SOME_FETCH_SIZE)`
>
> In JDBC you create a connection object, and from that connection you
>   create statements. When you execute the statments you get a result
>   set.
>
> Now, every one of these objects needs to be closed, but if you close
>   statement, the entry set is closed, and if you close the connection
>   all the statements are closed and their result sets.
>
> We were used to short living queries with connections of their own so
>   we never closed statements assuming the connection will handle the
>   things once it is closed.
>
> The problem was now with this long transaction (~24 hours) which never
>   closed the connection. The statements were never closed. Apparently,
>   the statement object holds resources both on the server that runs the
>   code and on the PostgreSQL database.
>
> My best guess to what resources are left in the DB is the things
>   related to the cursor. The statements that used the cursor were never
>   closed, so the result set they returned never closed as well. This
>   meant the database didn't free the relevant cursor resources in the
>   DB, and since it was over a huge table it took a lot of RAM.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for answers. But my question is about oomkiller mainly. Does it run on AWS Postgres RDS or not ?

Comment: It probably runs, but I didn't find any official reference so far. Please check this [Stack Exchange thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206448/postgresql-large-transaction-oom-killer) talking about a similar issue in PostgreSQL -- they ended up discovering that they had a long connection with auto commit set to false. Despite of everything, I would recommend you to double check all recommendations listed in RDS' documentation.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:  If you need PostgreSQL on AWS and you need rock solid stability, run PostgreSQL on EC2 (for now) and do some kernel tuning for overcommitting

---

I'll try to be concise, but you're not the only one who has seen this and it is a known (internal to Amazon) issue with RDS and Aurora PostgreSQL.

**OOM Killer on RDS/Aurora**

The OOM killer does run on RDS and Aurora instances because they are backed by linux VMs and OOM is an integral part of the kernel.

**Root Cause**

The root cause is that the default Linux kernel configuration assumes that you have virtual memory (swap file or partition), but EC2 instances (and the VMs that back RDS and Aurora) do not have virtual memory by default.  There is a single partition and no swap file is defined.  When linux thinks it has virtual memory, it uses a strategy called "overcommitting" which means that it allows processes to request and be granted a larger amount of memory than the amount of ram the system actually has.  Two tunable parameters govern this behavior:

**vm.overcommit_memory** - governs whether the kernel allows overcommitting (0=yes=default)
**vm.overcommit_ratio** - what percent of system+swap the kernel can overcommit.  If you have 8GB of ram and 8GB of swap, and your vm.overcommit_ratio = 75, the kernel will grant up to 12GB or memory to processes.

We set up an EC2 instance (where we could tune these parameters) and the following settings completely stopped PostgreSQL backends from getting killed:

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 75
```

vm.overcommit_memory = 2 tells linux not to overcommit (work within the constraints of system memory) and vm.overcommit_ratio = 75 tells linux not to grant requests for more than 75% of memory (only allow user processes to get up to 75% of memory).

We have an open case with AWS and they have committed to coming up with a long-term fix (using kernel tuning params or cgroups, etc) but we don't have an ETA yet.  If you are having this problem, I encourage you to open a case with AWS and reference case #5881116231 so they are aware that you are impacted by this issue, too.

In short, if you need stability in the near term, use PostgreSQL on EC2.  If you must use RDS or Aurora PostgreSQL, you will need to oversize your instance (at additional cost to you) and hope for the best as oversizing doesn't guarantee you won't still have the problem.